# How does grad() works in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, gradient, autograd

I need some conceptual clarity with the inputs of the Pytorch grad() function.
Please see the following code:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([6., 4.], requires_grad=True)
Q = 1/3*a**3 - 1/2*b**2
```

Here, I have defined 3 tensors, I was trying to compute the derivative of `Q` w.r.t `a`.
The following line would simply compute the first and second derivatives.

```
Q_a = torch.autograd.grad(Q.sum(), a, create_graph=True)[0]
Q_aa = torch.autograd.grad(Q_a.sum(), a, create_graph=True)[0]
print('Q_a =',Q_a.detach().numpy())
print('Q_aa =',Q_aa.detach().numpy())
```

The output is:

```
Q_a = [4. 9.]
Q_aa = [4. 6.]
```

I am wondering that, why do I need to pass `Q.sum()` or `Q_a.sum()` which is just 1 value and the second argument `a` has two values.

```
>>> print(Q.sum())
>>> tensor(-14.3333, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
>>> print(a)
>>> tensor([2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
```

Can someone explain to me how does `Q.sum()` helps in computing the correct gradient. Is it possible to compute the derivatives with just `Q` not `Q.sum()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your question is based on wrong assumption. You said ..

> I was trying to compute the derivative of `Q` w.r.t `a`

NO. you are not. In the code sample you provided, *you are trying to compute the derivative of `Q.sum()` w.r.t `a`* - they are different things.

"Derivative of `Q` w.r.t `a`" is *matrix* called [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), whereas ..

"Derivative of `Q.sum()` w.r.t `a`" is a *vector* known as [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).

Both can be computed and are used in different places for achieving different things. Its your decision which one you want.

Comment: You are right. I found an excellent blog on how they actually do the backdrop. https://blog.paperspace.com/pytorch-101-understanding-graphs-and-automatic-differentiation/